# Element wise average in dictionary of lists

Tags: python

I have a very large python dictionary. I want to perform an element-wise averaging for each element in each list. Let's say:

```
dict = {
    "a": [2,5,3],
    "b": [1,0,2],
    "c": [5,2,5]
}
```

The output should be: `[2.6 2.3 3.3]` where each element is the average of all the elements at that index in all the lists in dictionary.

This naive approach does not seem efficient because the dictionary is very large and so are the lists in dictionary.

```
avg = np.zeros(3)
for item in dict.values():
    for x in range(0,3):
        avg[x] += item[x]
for x in range(0,3):
    avg[x] /= 3
print(avg)
```

How to do this efficiently?

Comment: A library like pandas may help although I don't know how fast it can convert such dictionary to a dataframe.

Comment: Did you time this and determine it is not performant enough?

Comment: @TomKarzes Maybe "right", but not good. Bad idea to use a numpy array like that. Simply using a list instead (`avg = [0] * size`) makes it ~4 times faster. And >10 times faster is possible, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems 2-3 times faster than mozway's fastest (for size 1000x1000):

```
avg = [sum(column) / len(column)
       for column in zip(*d.values())]
```

Benchmarked on [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=jVTBjtMwEL1wylf4VnvJZrPAIhQpX8CFe6gi09hdi9iObKc0rfolXPYCd36Bz-BrsMdO07ICkVM88-b5zZuRv34fJveo1dPTt9Hx23e_Xowd4-g96_sJd6TKkP8Mc6NRqLGjxBvdj1IRdId6ps4nrg2K_0godBADvumKHe1HZjEh6yw7k7ZcMqr-pO6FdVjSAUM2f8ZASKT4RI1rtRFboWiPO7FxiYfutqhGaigOzGiL78uyJJAIyoRjMugK-DNnrJsh-5A3VG0ZLnOoXvKJv9mv0csayPxv9j-VqequRiFx2bDPxI6kPnyhU6tGOTwz3LdDjaETBnsu7SjARLoXti5J4TQAyBXjP23-u8t8VBvrrYRh5Zczy6_dz6-k55fXZpmQgzYu2NJpmXGjJXJCMuFQysRTjrxgOvauDWeDqIWEiRXWUecFC68nVUUZSY11HdvNN4GIUK-GOWQn6w3xrRxFlZQUm0ctNr7XOK_7kuTocw1Di4uyzBKCpywLeoIfR16hZg0oHlDg0wkMDzot5slqF9CNQzfonr0GvAt46yWxDgNdw9ekqR7W68vZ8NURRuYsqd4Wr_gJ_fyBjtAkxN5ATFq0ygJpu0h9mFfuWtyyhq70ksBYTJat98uxIJKsgg4DU1GmB6NbX0uyM29qAui9c2yqofd0_WCEcnh2w8-paFtFJWtbv1cxufqoPsB7U63yMKBix4wVWpH4-qRHaH6MfgM):

```
 19.09 ± 0.03 ms  Kelly
 26.33 ± 0.19 ms  Kelly_fmean
 51.09 ± 0.25 ms  mozway_numpy
249.17 ± 1.17 ms  bart_original
266.40 ± 5.85 ms  mozway_mean

Python: 3.11.4 (main, Sep  9 2023, 15:09:21) [GCC 13.2.1 20230801]
```

In mozway's test, bart_original was *slower* than mozway_mean, so let me try on two more systems:

On replit.com:

```
 16.58 ± 0.20 ms  Kelly
 19.62 ± 0.17 ms  Kelly_fmean
 34.98 ± 0.10 ms  mozway_numpy
184.64 ± 0.25 ms  bart_original
244.38 ± 0.78 ms  mozway_mean

Python: 3.10.11 (main, Apr  4 2023, 22:10:32) [GCC 12.2.0]
```

On trinket.io:

```
 24.17 ± 0.50 ms  Kelly
 31.63 ± 0.64 ms  Kelly_fmean
 75.26 ± 1.96 ms  mozway_numpy
261.52 ± 7.42 ms  bart_original
289.71 ± 10.68 ms  mozway_mean

Python: 3.10.9 (main, Jan 23 2023, 22:32:48) [GCC 10.2.1 20210110]
```

Benchmark script:

```py
def Kelly(d):
    return [sum(column) / len(column) for column in zip(*d.values())]

def Kelly_fmean(d):
    return list(map(fmean, zip(*d.values())))

def bart_original(dict):
    avg = np.zeros(1000)
    for item in dict.values():
        for x in range(0,1000):
            avg[x] += item[x]
    for x in range(0,1000):
        avg[x] /= 1000
    return avg

def mozway_numpy(d):
    return np.array(list(d.values())).mean(axis=0).tolist()

def mozway_mean(d):
    return list(map(mean, zip(*d.values())))

funcs = Kelly, Kelly_fmean, bart_original, mozway_numpy, mozway_mean

import random
from timeit import timeit, default_timer as timer
from statistics import mean, fmean, stdev
import numpy as np
import sys

d = {i: random.choices(range(10), k=1000) for i in range(1000)}

times = {f: [] for f in funcs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):6.2f} ± {stdev(ts):4.2f} ms '
for _ in range(50):
    for f in funcs:
        t0 = timer()
        f(d)
        times[f].append(timer() - t0)
for f in sorted(funcs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)

print('\nPython:', sys.version)
```

Comment: You are correct @Kelly Bundy. Your approach is the fastest, I did run it. I will use this approach. Thank you.

Comment: could you also take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77083307/22487733) question please @Kelly Bundy?

Comment: @bart I have no idea what tensors are. Also, what does that have to do with this question / my answer?

Comment: it has nothing to do with this question. I was wondering if you have any good solution for the problem in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77083307/22487733) question as well.

Answer (score 4):

I'd use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`statistics.mean`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean) to compute the mean without intermediate:

```
from statistics import mean

d = {
    "a": [2,5,3],
    "b": [1,0,2],
    "c": [5,2,5]
}

out = list(map(mean, zip(*d.values())))
```

Output:

```
[2.6666666666666665, 2.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335]
```

Alternatively:

```
out = [round(mean(x), 2) for x in zip(*d.values())]
```

Output: `[2.67, 2.33, 3.33]`

Or, as you used [numpy](/questions/tagged/numpy):

```
out = np.array(list(d.values())).mean(axis=0).tolist()
```

###### timings

Using a 1000 x 1000 input (`d = {i: [5]*1000 for i in range(1000)}`)

```
# original approach (replacing the hardcoded 3 with 1000)
166 ms ± 4.94 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# list(map(mean, zip(*d.values())))
137 ms ± 1.88 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# [round(mean(x), 2) for x in zip(*d.values())]
150 ms ± 12.6 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# np.array(list(d.values())).mean(axis=0).tolist()
30.8 ms ± 609 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: If one of these options is not performant enough, I feel like python is likely the wrong language to address the problem.

Comment: Thank you @mozway. How can I profile the time like you did? e.g. `166 ms ± 4.94` how do I get this for a code snippit?

Comment: Using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html). If you use `jupyter`, add `%%timeit` as first line of the cell

Comment: `mean` is not for speed. For me, that's actually slower than the OP's, on two different systems. How fast are my solutions for you?