# Count how many elements of one Tensor exists in another Tensor

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor

I have two 1D tensors:

```
A = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
B = torch.tensor([2, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15, 16])
```

The tensors are **extremely huge**, different in lengths, and the values are neighter in sequence nor sorted.

I want to get the count of the number of elements of B that (i) exists in A (ii) do not exist in A. So, the output will be:

```
Exists: 4
Do not exist: 3
```

I have tried:

```
exists = torch.eq(A,B).sum().item()
not_exist = torch.numel(B) - exists
```

But this gives the error:

```
RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (10) must match the size of tensor b (7) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

The following approach works but it involves creating a `boolean` tensor first and then summing up the `true` elements. Is it efficient for very large tensors?

```
exists = np.isin(A,B).sum()
not_exist = torch.numel(B) - exists
```

Is there any better or more efficient approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :
import torch

```
A = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
B = torch.tensor([2, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15, 16])

# Convert tensors to sets
setA = set(A.numpy())
setB = set(B.numpy())

# Find intersection and difference
intersection = setA & setB
difference = setB - setA

# Calculate the counts
exists = len(intersection)
not_exist = len(difference)

print(f"Exists: {exists}")
print(f"Do not exist: {not_exist}")
```

### Update :

You can sticki with native PyTorch methods like broadcasting. This approach might be more memory-intensive, but can be more efficient for large tensors, especially when using GPU acceleration.

```
import torch

A = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
B = torch.tensor([2, 5, 6, 8, 12, 15, 16])

# Use broadcasting to compare each element of B with all of A
# The result will be a 2D tensor with shape (len(B), len(A))
comparison_matrix = B[:, None] == A

# Sum along the second axis will give a tensor where each element
# indicates how many times an element from B was found in A
matches_per_element = comparison_matrix.sum(dim=1)

# Calculate the counts
exists = (matches_per_element > 0).sum().item()
not_exist = len(B) - exists

print(f"Exists: {exists}")
print(f"Do not exist: {not_exist}")
```

Comment: Thank you @Amira Bedhiafi. My concern is, is creating two sets from extremely large tensors and then finding the intersection and difference arrays the fastest or efficient approach? I have to consider the memory consumption as well.